# How to name method that raises an event

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have a method (Read) that raise an event when there are new logs:

```
public class LoggerModel: ILoggerModel {
  public event System.EventHandler LogsChanged;
  ...
  public void Read() {
     if (ThereAreNewLogs()) {
        OnLogsChanged(System.EventArgs.Empty);
     }
  }
}
```

but I feel that "Read()" is not expressive...any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call it `CheckIfLogChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of taste, I personally use `TriggerEvent`, where "event" is the name of the event of course. It's also a good place to check whether the event is not null. But it's a private method in my case, whereas your `Read` method is public, and if raising an event requires calling some reminder-method "manually", it is at odds with the very idea of event-based communication imho.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's confusing... I would call it Listen() or something like that.. perhaps StartListening()

In addition you have to check if someone has registered for the OnLogsChanged Event

by calling

```
if(OnLogsChanged != null)
{
  OnLogsChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real scope of that method is to verify that and handle new entries in log.

So for me could be VerifyNewLogs, or something like this.

But the best solution it would be to add the documentation for it, where you will describe what the method is doing. This will for sure help you or someone else in the future.